# Powershell Form watching wsusutil.exe until finished

Tags: powershell

This is my first form I'm making to accomplish a task, but also to learn how to do it.  I'm making a simple front end for exporting and then importing WSUS data from a connected server to a disconnected server.  I'm working on the export part now and I need to figure out how to start the export process, then once it is done then make the iso file.

Here is the button code I have so far, but not sure how to watch the WsusUtil.exe until it's done then proceed to the next task. I thought I could watch the process and when it's over move to the next step.  But have not been able to make that work.  I tried a do until, but it kept running the start-process over and over. Also when it starts it make a large black box with some message on it.  I tried to use the -NoNewWindow but it did launched.   [WsusUtil.exe running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7A8q.png)

```
  $btnStartExport.Add_Click({
 
  $nicedate = get-date -UFormat %m-%d-%y #put in MM-DD-YY format
  
  #progress bar for overall progress of steps 1 and 2 and individual progress bar for each steps

  $WSUSUtilPath = "c:\Program Files\Update Services\Tools\"
  $WSUSMetaDataPath = "c:\tools\wsusexport\"
  $isotitle = "WSUS Offline Server update $nicedate"
  $ProcessName = "WsusUtil" #process to watch until it's done
  $isofilename = "WSUSSvrOffline-$nicedate.iso" #creates WSUS Offline Server update-11-14-2021.iso
  

  #Step 1 Check if directory exists 
  Check-Path $WSUSMetaDataPath

  #Step 1 - export the WSUS Metadata 
  Start-process -FilePath $WSUSUtilPath\WsusUtil.exe -ArgumentList @("export","$WSUSMetaDataPath\$nicedate-export.xml.gz","$WSUSMetaDataPath\$nicedate-export.log") -NoNewWindow -Wait 
  $wsusProcess = get-process WsusUtil -ErrorAction SilentyContinue
  
  # Step 2 - create ISO

  get-childitem "$WSUSMetaDataPath","$txtWSUSContentPath.text" | New-IsoFile -path $txtISOLocation.text+$isofilename -Force -Title $isotitle
  
  #clean up medatadata directory
  get-childitem -path $WSUSMetaDataPath -Include *.* -File -Recurse | foreach {$_.Delete()}
  
})
$frmMain.controls.add($btnStartExport)
```

Comment: You may try `Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden -Wait`. This should work.

Comment: that works thanks, any idea on watching the process until it's done? It take about 10 min to finish the wsusutil process.  Need to give some indication that the task is working, so the user does not try and stop it.

Comment: `Write-Progress` may do the job, but you can't use the `-Wait` then and monitor the process running in a loop. There is no way to know how much time it takes so it is difficult to write a progress. You may pop a message to instruct the user the process is long running and wait for the process to complete without closing the window. 
You may probably disable the capacity to close the form, but the user may still kill the process.